# How to avoid a NullPointerException being skipped in a JSF method expression?

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, jsf-2.2

I understood that JSF can be configured to convert `null` into `""` (and the other way around?). I think that's horrible because it has potential to hide errors, but I see the point since it's used in a web frontend/web frontend-backend data transfer environemnt.

However, in the following example I wonder whether skipping the `NullPointerException` which should be thrown because `backingBean0.property0` is `null` is a bit too much and it's imo trivial to see that this can cost you hours of debugging if you don't start to extract a MCVE immediately:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{backingBean0.createLabel(backingBean0.property0.property0)}"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

`BackingBean0`:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BackingBean0 implements Serializable {
    private Entity0 property0 = null;

    public Entity0 getProperty0() {
        return property0;
    }

    public void setProperty0(Entity0 property0) {
        this.property0 = property0;
    }

    public String createLabel(String value) {
        if(value == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("value mustn't be null");
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

`Entity0`:

```
public class Entity0 {
    private String property0;

    public String getProperty0() {
        return property0;
    }

    public void setProperty0(String property0) {
        this.property0 = property0;
    }
}
```

How can I turn this behaviour off, i.e. make the page load fail because of the NullPointerException thrown during the EL evaluation? Am I maybe not getting a core concept of JSF here?

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.2 on Payara 4.1.2.181.

Comment: an NPE has **_nothing_** to do with passing null or ""  it is up to you how to handle either of them

Comment: @kukeltje Please elaborate where you get the impression that I might thing different from that in my post. The introduction referring to getting `""` for `null` is an example of non-obvious JSF configuration results. Is it clear where the null pointer exception ought to be thrown, here (unrelated to `""` or `null` being received in the backing bean)?

Comment: it IS obvious configuration since YOU configure it (or not).

Comment: @kukeltje OK, replace configuration with default configuration which I didn't configure.

Comment: Why do you exactly want this behaviour? You state you turned something that you did not turn on yourself. I cannot really comment on your question since I fail to soo the issue. You check all possible empty strings with validators there are no issues. Having an application crash is bad behaviour. Or do you mean during development?

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way, this can be a solution:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BackingBean0 implements Serializable {

    private Entity0 property0;
    // serialVersionUID is important to serialize your bean
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Try to instance your variable before render page, see below:
    @PostConstruct
    public void beanInit(){
        property0 = new Entity0();
    }
    ...
}
```

Or in your .xhtml file:

```
</html>
...
<h:body>
  <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="1">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{backingBean0.createLabel(backingBean0.property0.property0)}"
                   rendered="#{backingBean0.property0 != null}">/>
  </h:panelGrid>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Or configure error pages in your web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/faces/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/faces/error-page-not-found.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: This approach only works if `property0` was immutable which is not possible or very bad practice for a backing bean property.

Comment: And if you use rendered attribute in your .xhtml?

Comment: I'm not asking how to check for `null` (should be `ne null` btw), but how to make the application crash when encountering `null` rather than use the empty string or else instead.

Comment: Check for null is exatcly for this, or catch an exception and ignore it, there is no other way to control this. A last alternative is config an error page.

Comment: The error would never the shown since the exception doesn't occur. I don't want to handle the exception, I want it to be thrown and crash the application.

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation002.htm#top

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>
        javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL
    </param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```